# If I define one or more binary operations that form group(s) over a set, is it correct to call it an algebra?

Tags: group-theory, advice

More specifically, I defined the operations multiplication (non-Abelian, composition of permutations) and addition (Abelian, modulo addition of bounded naturals) over the same set, that can be seen as a bounded set of naturals or permutations equivalently.
Is it formally correct to call it an algebra?

**Is it acceptable to call it an algebra in any informal sense?**

The two operations are not (at least doesn't seem to be) related to each other in any way like the usual ones (+ and *). Although, it would be interesting to know about an incidental relation.

Some entries [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Definition) seem to relate the concept of *algebra* to vectors, which is not my case (I suppose).

A use that seems non-related to vectors is in [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)
which borrows the word *algebra* from the fact it uses [algebraic structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure).

Answer (score 1):

Any set of (finitary) operations, obeying any list of axioms, can be called an algebra according to the terminology of the field of [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).  These are special cases of algebras for [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)).

But generally the more interesting question is whether that class of operations and axioms is of a particular form, has particular behavior, etc.  For example, my first question about your two operations is whether they obey a compatibility condition and what form it takes.